# Including topics in search results

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm interested in getting topics as part of the results when searching with:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?
```

For instance, when searching `Dance Music` on the YouTube website, it shows some videos and on the side there's a `Electronic Dance Music` topic showing up.

How can I get that using the API?

I'll also be fine search for topics in a different API call.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Search: list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) method which returns a collection of search results that match the query parameters specified in the API request. By default, a search result set identifies matching [`video`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos), [`channel`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels), and [`playlist`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists) resources, but you can also configure queries to only retrieve a specific type of resource such as the `topicId` parameter.

The `topicId` parameter indicates that the API response should only contain resources associated with the specified topic. The value identifies a Freebase topic ID.

> Important: Due to the deprecation of Freebase and the Freebase API, the topicId parameter started working differently as of February 27, 2017. At that time, YouTube started supporting a small set of curated topic IDs, and you can only use that smaller set of IDs as values for this parameter.

You may use the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?q=surfing&maxResults=25&part=snippet) to try the sample request.